# CDbExpression('NOW()') return empty

Tags: mysql, yii

I have a model with rules

```
array('created', 'default', 'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
            'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
```

But i got this error "Field 'created' doesn't have a default value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the 'on' you're using.

The on refers to scenarios in Yii for which the rule applies.

So you can try using $model->setScenario('insert'); before calling the save() method and in should work or you could remove that part from the validation rule